# When do you have to apply continuity correction?

Tags: statistics

I've solved the following problem.

> An electronics firm receives, on the average, fifty orders per week for a particular silicon chip. If the company has sixty chips on hand, use the Central Limit Theorem to approximate the probability that they will be unable to fill all their orders for the upcoming week. Assume that weekly demands follow a Poisson distribution.

$
\mu = \lambda = 50; \sigma = \sqrt\lambda = 5\sqrt2; n = 1$

Therefore $$P(X>60) = 1 - P(X<60) = 1 - P(Z<\frac{60-50}{5\sqrt2}) = 1 - P(Z<\sqrt2) = 0.07927 $$

But if we apply continuity correction,

$$P(X>60) = 1 - P(Z < \frac{60.5-50}{5\sqrt2}) = 0.0694$$

So, when and why should I or should I not use continuity correction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually better to do the continuity correction when approximating an integer-valued distribution by a normal distribution, but it may not make any significant difference when the normal approximation is very accurate, which occurs for Poisson($\lambda$) for very large $\lambda$. This is just because $\Phi(x)$ and $\Phi(x+0.5/\sigma)$, where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF, are not really all that different when $\sigma$ is huge. In this problem $\sigma$ is just $\sqrt{50}$ which is not really all that big, so it makes a pretty significant difference.

With that being said, software can more directly evaluate the desired quantity without having to use a normal approximation at all. For example you can ask Matlab for poisscdf(60,50,'upper') which gives about 0.0722. You can see that this is somewhat closer to your continuity-corrected result than the other one.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes a lot of sense now. What I'm noticing is that rounding in these kind of problems leads to greater error than I would've thought